# Find and concat string based on 2 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In col B, I want to find all "Add:" strings from C:D range for each Source(col A). I do not want to fetch any other value. I have tried using vlookups and index/match but I am not able to get the array of strings and concat them using a formula. I do not want to use VBA.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Office 365 then you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(($C$2:$C$12 = A2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ADD:",$D$2:$D$12))),$D$2:$D$12,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel then you will need VBA.

Place this in a Module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr) As String
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    If TEXTJOIN <> "" Then
        TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
    Else
        TEXTJOIN = ""
    End If
End Function
```

I had to use TEXTJOIN2 as the Function name in my formula in the photo.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with v2010. Thanks for the quick turnaround.

Comment: @user11087823 wrap in IFERROR()

Comment: I got it working by changing all the coded TEXTJOIN to TEXTJOIN2.

Comment: @user11087823 I fixed the code to deal with the null return.

Comment: Your VBA solution worked beautifully but it turned out to be bit more complex than I was expecting.